# sryza/spark-timeseries: NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.IntRef.create(I)Lscala/runtime/IntRef;

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a Scala project that I build with sbt.  It uses the [sryza/spark-timeseries library](https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries).

I am trying to run the following simple code:

```
  val tsAirPassengers = new DenseVector(Array(
    112.0,118.0,132.0,129.0,121.0,135.0,148.0,148.0,136.0,119.0,104.0,118.0,115.0,126.0,
    141.0,135.0,125.0,149.0,170.0,170.0,158.0,133.0,114.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,178.0,163.0,
    172.0,178.0,199.0,199.0,184.0,162.0,146.0,166.0,171.0,180.0,193.0,181.0,183.0,218.0,
    230.0,242.0,209.0,191.0,172.0,194.0,196.0,196.0,236.0,235.0,229.0,243.0,264.0,272.0,
    237.0,211.0,180.0,201.0,204.0,188.0,235.0,227.0,234.0,264.0,302.0,293.0,259.0,229.0,
    203.0,229.0,242.0,233.0,267.0,269.0,270.0,315.0,364.0,347.0,312.0,274.0,237.0,278.0,
    284.0,277.0,317.0,313.0,318.0,374.0,413.0,405.0,355.0,306.0,271.0,306.0,315.0,301.0,
    356.0,348.0,355.0,422.0,465.0,467.0,404.0,347.0,305.0,336.0,340.0,318.0,362.0,348.0,
    363.0,435.0,491.0,505.0,404.0,359.0,310.0,337.0,360.0,342.0,406.0,396.0,420.0,472.0,
    548.0,559.0,463.0,407.0,362.0,405.0,417.0,391.0,419.0,461.0,472.0,535.0,622.0,606.0,
    508.0,461.0,390.0,432.0
  ))

val period = 12
val model = HoltWinters.fitModel(tsAirPassengers, period, "additive", "BOBYQA")
```

It builds fine, but when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.IntRef.create(I)Lscala/runtime/IntRef;
    at com.cloudera.sparkts.models.HoltWintersModel.convolve(HoltWinters.scala:252)
    at com.cloudera.sparkts.models.HoltWintersModel.initHoltWinters(HoltWinters.scala:277)
    at com.cloudera.sparkts.models.HoltWintersModel.getHoltWintersComponents(HoltWinters.scala:190)
.
.
.
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
val model = HoltWinters.fitModel(tsAirPassengers, period, "additive", "BOBYQA")
```

My *build.sbt* includes:

```
name := "acme-project"
version := "0.0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.6.0",
  "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.5+",
  "com.github.seratch" %% "awscala" % "0.3.+",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.6.2"
)
```

I have placed *sparkts-0.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar* in the *lib* folder of my project.  (I would have preferred to add a libraryDependency, but *spark-ts* does not appear to be on Maven Central.)

What is causing this run-time error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library requires Scala 2.11, not 2.10, and Spark 2.0, not 1.6.2, as you can see from

```
<scala.minor.version>2.11</scala.minor.version>
<scala.complete.version>${scala.minor.version}.8</scala.complete.version>
<spark.version>2.0.0</spark.version>
```

in `pom.xml`. You can try changing these and seeing if it still compiles, find which older version of `sparkts` is compatible with your versions, or update your project's Scala and Spark versions (don't miss `spark-mllib_2.10` in this case).

Also, if you put the jar into `lib` folder, you also have to put its dependencies there (and their dependencies, etc.) or into `libraryDependencies`. Instead, publish `sparkts` into your local repository using `mvn install` (IIRC) and add it to `libraryDependencies`, which will allow SBT to resolve its dependencies.